# Cleaning addresses - add last token in street name (Ave, St,..) where missing, based on other records

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, stringr

In the example data below, some addresses are missing the last 'token' making up the street name - ave, st, dr, etc. I'm using OSM for geocoding and I find these records get a hit, but often in some other country. I would like to clean them further by adding the most likely missing token based on other records in the data.

```
valid_ends <- c("AVE", "ST", "EXT", "BLVD")

data.frame(address = c("75 NEW PARK AVE", "245 NEW PARK AVE", "42 NEW PARK",
                       "934 NEW PARK ST", "394 NEW PARK", "34 ASYLUM ST",
                       "42 ASYLUM", "953 ASYLUM AVE", "23 ASYLUM ST",
                       "65 WASHINGTON AVE EXT", "94 WASHINGTON AVE")) %>% 
    mutate(addr_tokens = str_split(address, " ")) %>%
    mutate(addr_fix = NA)
```

Desired result: a new character column ("addr_fix") added to the above which contains an "augmented" address for records 3, 5, 7 ("AVE", "AVE", "ST"...respectively). Those which are augmented are done so based on the last address token not being contained in valid_ends. The token which is appended to the one which occurs most frequently for that street (matched based on removing the numeric first token and the valid end tokens from addresses in the dataset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little messy, but this approach should work:

1. Start by getting the "core address" - the street name without suffix - and copying the suffix/"valid end", if there is one, to `end`:

```r
valid_ends_rgx <- paste0(valid_ends, collapse = "|")

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(has_valid_end = str_detect(address, valid_ends_rgx),
         core_addr = 
           str_remove_all(address, valid_ends_rgx) %>% 
           str_trim() %>% 
           str_remove("\\d+ "),
         end = str_match(address, valid_ends_rgx)[, 1]
         ) 

df2
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   address               has_valid_end core_addr  end  
   <chr>                 <lgl>         <chr>      <chr>
 1 75 NEW PARK AVE       TRUE          NEW PARK   AVE  
 2 245 NEW PARK AVE      TRUE          NEW PARK   AVE  
 3 42 NEW PARK           FALSE         NEW PARK   NA   
 4 934 NEW PARK ST       TRUE          NEW PARK   ST   
 5 394 NEW PARK          FALSE         NEW PARK   NA   
 6 34 ASYLUM ST          TRUE          ASYLUM     ST   
 7 42 ASYLUM             FALSE         ASYLUM     NA   
 8 953 ASYLUM AVE        TRUE          ASYLUM     AVE  
 9 23 ASYLUM ST          TRUE          ASYLUM     ST   
10 65 WASHINGTON AVE EXT TRUE          WASHINGTON AVE  
11 94 WASHINGTON AVE     TRUE          WASHINGTON AVE
```

2. Find the most common valid ending for each street:

```r
replacements <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(core_addr, end) %>% 
  summarise(end_ct = n()) %>% 
  group_by(core_addr) %>% 
  summarise(most_end = end[which.max(end_ct)])
  
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  core_addr  most_end
  <chr>      <chr>   
1 ASYLUM     ST      
2 NEW PARK   AVE     
3 WASHINGTON AVE
```

3. Update the `address` fields with missing ends, based on the `most_end` field in `replacements.

```r
df2 %>% 
  left_join(replacements, by = "core_addr") %>% 
  transmute(
    address = if_else(has_valid_end, address, str_c(address, most_end, sep = " "))
  )

# A tibble: 11 x 1
   address              
   <chr>                
 1 75 NEW PARK AVE      
 2 245 NEW PARK AVE     
 3 42 NEW PARK AVE      
 4 934 NEW PARK ST      
 5 394 NEW PARK AVE     
 6 34 ASYLUM ST         
 7 42 ASYLUM ST         
 8 953 ASYLUM AVE       
 9 23 ASYLUM ST         
10 65 WASHINGTON AVE EXT
11 94 WASHINGTON AVE
```

Comment: five star answer, thx